# Unable to load a Knockout Component - Unknown template value: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This is how I am using the component and sending the parameters using a Custom Element:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="with: DevoteeList">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ko-pager params="Data: Devotees, 
                    Modifier: $parent.DevoteeModifier, 
                    PageCount: DevoteesPageCount(), 
                    Url: '@Url.Action("SelectDevotees", "Devotee", new { a = 1 })'"></ko-pager>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how I am defining a Knockout Component. It is a Pager that I want to use at few places. But, I am receiving the error: `Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return SelectDevotees }"
Message: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return DevoteeList }"
Message: Unable to process binding "component: function () { return l }"
Message: Component 'ko-pager': Unknown template value: [object Object]`

```
ko.components.register('ko-pager', {
        viewModel: function (params) {
            var self = this;
            self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
            self.pages = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.PageCount = ko.observable(params.PageCount);



        //self.currentPage.subscribe(function (nv) {
        //    self.GetPage(self.parent);
        //});

        self.GetPages = function () {
            for (var i = 1; i <= params.PageCount ; i++) {
                self.pages.push(i);
            }
            return self.pages;
        };

        self.FirstPage = function () {
            self.GetPage(1);
        };
        self.PrevPage = function () {
            if (self.currentPage() > 1) {
                var pn = self.currentPage() - 1;
                self.GetPage(pn);
            }
        };
        self.LastPage = function () {
            self.GetPage(params.PageCount);
        };
        self.NextPage = function () {
            if (self.currentPage() < params.PageCount) {
                var pn = self.currentPage() + 1;
                self.GetPage(pn);
            }
        };

        self.GetPage = function (pg) {
            if (pg == null)
                pg = self.currentPage();
            else
                self.currentPage(pg);
            var url = params.Url + '&pageNumber=' + pg;
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                var t = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                if (params.Modifier) {
                    params.Modifier(t);
                }
                params.Data(t());
            });
        };
    },
    template: { element: document.getElementById('ko-ajax-pager') }
});

<div id="ko-ajax-pager" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;" data-bind="visible: PageCount > 1">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="First" class="btn" data-bind="click: FirstPage" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Prev" class="btn" data-bind="click: PrevPage" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select data-bind="options: GetPages(), value: currentPage, event: { change: GetPage(null) }">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Next" class="btn" data-bind="click: NextPage" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Last" class="btn" data-bind="click: LastPage" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please figure out, what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using the default component loader? Can you put a breakpoint in [this line](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/components/defaultLoader.js#L103) and see if it's being hit? You can see the error you describe in L129, which means your template config isn't correctly passed... I'd expect an error in L123 instead of 129.

Comment: I am not using any loader, I didn't read about that I need to use it, thinking the default loading works without any extra JS. Do I need to use a loader for default loading also?

Comment: The default loader is fine, I just don't understand how you can get your specific error message when registering with `template: { element: /* ... */ }`. So it'd help if you could either reproduce the problem in a snippet for us, or report the value of `templateConfig` in the knockout code I've linked above.

Comment: Instead of a `<div>`, I have used now `<template id=abc>` and it is now loading.